# Creating an array to read the number of words in a line

Tags: javascript

Hi guys so i am doing an exercise and one of the questions has asked me to "Create an algorithm that puts words divided by space with a max 100 character line length" So basically there is an array of 1000 words or so and its suppose to put 100 words per line, and spaces don't count. It also says :

```
Given N words where N >= 1000
Create rows of words separated by spaces where row length >= 100
Once a word has been used it should be considered removed.
Add to a simple SPA
```

Now i have done this to the best of my ability but i created my own set of words, i was wondering how to change it to use an array and also how to remove it when its done been used. To be honset i am not sure what SPA means at all , so if someone can explain that, that would be fantastic.

```
const paragraph = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam nibh. Nunc varius facilisis eros. Sed erat. In in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet. Curabitur adipiscing luctus massa. Integer ut purus ac augue commodo commodo. Nunc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer. Etiam vitae nisl. In dignissim lacus ut ante. Cras elit lectus, bibendum a, adipiscing vitae, commodo et, dui. Ut tincidunt tortor. Donec nonummy, enim in lacinia pulvinar, velit tellus scelerisque augue, ac posuere libero urna eget neque. Cras ipsum. Vestibulum pretium, lectus nec venenatis volutpat, purus lectus ultrices risus, a condimentum risus mi et quam. Pellentesque auctor fringilla neque. Duis eu massa ut lorem iaculis vestibulum. Maecenas facilisis elit sed justo. Quisque volutpat malesuada velit.",
    lines = Math.round(paragraph.length / 100);

let line = 0;

for (let i = 0; lines > i; i++) {
    document.body.innerHTML += paragraph.slice(line, line + 100) + '<br>';

  line += 100;
}
```

So i got it to go through my set of words and it worked fine but i just need to change it to use an array which is what i am trying to figure out

Thanks for all the help

Comment: "*and its suppose to put 100 words per line, and spaces don't count.*" - No. The instructions ask for "*max 100 character line length*".

Comment: I think SPA refers to [Single-Page-Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), a term that admittedly doesn't fit at all. "Add to simple SPA" seems to mean "output the result on a web page".

Comment: i think from what i understood that its suppose to be 100 words per line not including spaces , sorry my English is not the best

Comment: No, it says that each line should have 100 *[characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(computing))* (letters and spaces) or less.